# React consistent page elements

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've recently started using React for a project I'm working on and had a quick question.

I have a few page components I've created but want each one to have the same Header - currently their `render()` functions look like:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Header />
    ... {{ page specific elements here }}
  </div>
)
```

I was wondering if there is a way I can set elements that I want on every page (i.e. the header) to be consistent without manually inserting them into the `render` function of each component?

My main.js file is:

```
import Header from './components/Header'
import history from './history'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Link, Route, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import Discover from './pages/Discover';
import Layout from './pages/Layout';
import Search from './pages/Search';

const app = document.getElementById('app')

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Layout}/>
            <Route path='/discover' component={Discover}/>
            <Route path='/search' component={Search}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>,
app
)
```

And my index.html page:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="app"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="client.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the header to be consistently rendered across all routes inside the router, then just add `Header` component inside the router.

```
import Header from './components/Header'
import history from './history'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Link, Route, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import Discover from './pages/Discover';
import Layout from './pages/Layout';
import Search from './pages/Search';

const app = document.getElementById('app')

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
        <Header/> {//Just put it in here}
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Layout}/>
            <Route path='/discover' component={Discover}/>
            <Route path='/search' component={Search}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>,
app
)
```

If you want to avoid it showing up in a particular route like may be login, you can render login in `main.js` routes and then take the `Switch` to an inner Route.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
       <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
       <Route path='/' component={App}/>
    </Router>,
app
)
```

and then in the inner Route:

```
<div>
    <Header/> {//Just put it in here}
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/' component={Layout}/>
       <Route path='/discover' component={Discover}/>
       <Route path='/search' component={Search}/>
    </Switch>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it works, however React complained about the <Router> element only being allowed to have one child, so I wrapped the Header/Switch in a div! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [React Higher-Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

like this:

```
function withLayout(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
      return (
         <div>
             <Header /> // header or any thing
             <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
         </div>
      )
    }
  };
}
```

and in your page containers (example: Discover):

```
class Discover extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     }

     render() {
          return (
             <div>
                 blah blah .... I am discover page
             </div>
          )
      }
};
const discoverWithLayout = withLayout(Discover)
export default discoverWithLayout
```